Bidirectional @OneToMany @ManyToOne with Multi-Tenancy
We are using the Multi-Tenancy in the following structure, where Dog and Cow belong to different schema and NEVER co-exist in the same schema:

Parent Class, which is in both schema HOME and FARM:
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
...
public class Animal implements Serializable {...}

Child Class 1, which is in schema HOME:
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ANIMAL_ID")
...
public class Dog extends Animal {...}

Child Class 2, which is in schema FARM:
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ANIMAL_ID")
...
public class Cow extends Animal {...}


In this way, when we fetch the Animal entity by different repository, it will fetching only the corresponding child class, i.e., from DogRepository, it will do SELECT * FROM ANIMAL a JOIN DOG d ON a.ID = d.ANIMAL_ID, which essentially does SELECT * FROM HOME.ANIMAL a JOIN HOME.DOG d ON a.ID = d.ANIMAL_ID, and this is exactly what we want.
Now, inside the parent class, we have a field which has a bidirectional @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relationship:

Inside Animal.class:
@OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        mappedBy = "animal",
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<AnimalRelation> relationships;

Inside AnimalRelation.class:
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ANIMAL_ID")
private Animal animal;


Here comes the issue: when Animal entity has AnimalRelation inside, with the current structure, Hibernate is not able to know which child class it needs, i.e., even from DogRepository, it will do SELECT * FROM ANIMAL a LEFT JOIN DOG d ON a.ID = d.ANIMAL_ID JOIN COW c ON a.ID = c.ANIMAL_ID. But this causes issue as Dog and Cow are not in the same schema, so we get error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.
Here is the question: how can we require the subentity @ManyToOne to either joining Animal with Dog only, or fetching Animal only?
